# Tax Receipt (CDN TAX RECEIPTS)

Tags: receipts, cdn-tax-receipts

On our tax receipt (using CDN TAX RECEIPTS) it says: "Charitable Registration:" - Is there any plan to change that to read: "Charitable Registration Number" on the template?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a ts() wrapped string, you should be able to use Administer - Customize Data - Word Replacements to replace it. See https://github.com/jake-mw/CDNTaxReceipts/blob/1.5.1/cdntaxreceipts.functions.inc#L409. I haven't tested that.

To fully customize it you could implement hook_cdntaxreceipts_writeReceipt. See https://github.com/jake-mw/CDNTaxReceipts/blob/1.5.1/cdntaxreceipts.functions.inc#L301

Answer (score 1):

You can set this however you like in your template.

Comment: Yes and no, it's part of the pdf writing code (https://github.com/jake-mw/CDNTaxReceipts/blob/1.5.1/cdntaxreceipts.functions.inc#L409)

Comment: -> PDF template feature to completely customize the look of your Tax Receipt.